# Swift - error "Cannot subscript a value of '[String: DayData]' with an index of tye 'Int'

Tags: swift, uitableview

So I'm trying to create a table view that will take information from a source I've already concocted in a different view controller. I'm having some trouble when I try to pull the information into the cells of the table view.

I'm getting the error "Cannot subscript a value of '[String: DayData]' with an index of tye 'Int'" on the line that starts with "var (date, sales, doorsKnocked..."

I'm not sure how to fix this. Can anyone figure it out? Thanks!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


var allInformationByDate = [
"2016-08-13": DayData(sales: 0, doorsKnocked: 0, milesWalked: 0.00, hoursWorked: 0.00)
]

struct DayData { 
let sales: Int
let doorsKnocked: Int
let milesWalked: Double
let hoursWorked: Double
}

class historyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

//return Int, how many sections in table
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

//return Int, how many rows in table
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allInformationByDate.count
}

//what are the contents of each cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    var (date, sales, doorsKnocked, milesWalked, hoursWorked) = allInformationByDate[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Comment: `allInformationByDate` is a *dictionary*, not an array.

Comment: @MartinR So am I doomed? How can I use it for my table view?

Comment: I'd like to be able to list both keys and values. Thanks

Comment: A dictionary is a collection of keys and values in *unspecified* order. You probably want to create an *array* which contains the dates in the desired order.

Comment: @MartinR Can you even make an array that has multiple values for each key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `allInformationByDate` is a *dictionary* which contains the
keys and values in *unspecified order,* and cannot be accessed with an
integer subscript.

You should create an *array* which contains the dates in the desired order. In your case

```
let sortedDates = allInformationByDate.keys.sort()
```

would work. Then you can retrieve the data for an index path as

```
let date = sortedDates[indexPath.row]
let dayData = allInformationByDate[date]! // We _know_ that the dictionary value exists.
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much! Do you know how to get rid of the extra nonsense that's coming through so we just have the date and then the actual numbers? http://imgur.com/a/aVjUO

Comment: @adman: First you have to unwrap the dictionary value to get rid of the "Optional", I have updated the answer accordingly. Then you can print the separate fields (`dayData.sales`, ...) in any desired format. Or look-up the "CustomStringConvertible" protocol to define a customized output of your DayData structure.

Comment: is there a way to reverse the order so that they're in descending order?

Comment: @adman: `sort(>)` ? You should find that in the Swift book :)